# UserChecker - Use entity manager

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-security

My website is running Symfony 3.4 and I made my own user member system.
My User entity contains a Datetime field 'lastLogin' and I can't find a solution to update it every time a user logged in.

I created a custom UserChecker then I tried to update the field in it :

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Security;

use CoreBundle\Entity\User as AppUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }
        if ( $user->getDeleted() || !$user->getEnabled()  )
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
        else
        {
            // BELOW IS WHAT I TRY, BUT FAIL.
            $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe I can't use the doctrine entity manager in this file ?

If I use `$this->get('doctrine')->getManager();` I get :

> Fatal Error: Call to undefined method
>   CoreBundle\Security\UserChecker::get()

Comment: what is your exact issue? what fails? do you get any error message?

Comment: Does it give you any error . . I suppose it throws error regarding no get function available.  .right?

Comment: a very small proposal regarding conventions: you shouldn't use getDeleted or getEnabled for a boolean method, use isDeleted and isEnabled instead.

Comment: I edited my first topic with the error. Mea culpa.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution.  A good one.  However, your above code would work if you injected your entity manager like the listener below.  Try to avoid using getDoctrine even in your controllers.  I might add that it might be best to update your database using straight sql.  If other parts of your code are already using the entity manager then flushing it might cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunno why @doncallisto removed his post. It was (IMHO) the right thing.

Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events

So you have several options.

- `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` - triggers every time the user
  full out the login form and submit credentials. Will work, but you
  **won't get last_login updates** if you have `remember_me` cookie or similar
- `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` - triggers *each time*
  (every request) when authentication was successful. It means your `last_login` will be updated **each time** on **every** request unless user logged **out**

so you'll need a EventSubscriber. Take a look at this article. https://thisdata.com/blog/subscribing-to-symfonys-security-events/

MAybe you'll need a simplified version.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
        return array(
            // AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE => 'onAuthenticationFailure', // no need for this at that moment
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin', // this ist what you want
        );
}
```

and then the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` method itself.

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin( InteractiveLoginEvent $event )
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    if( $user instanceof User )
    {
      $user->setLastLogin( new \DateTime() );
      $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

P.S.
FosUserBundle uses interactive_login and a custom event to set last_login on entity
look at: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/LastLoginListener.php#L63

Comment: Creating a EventSuscriber works perfect ! Thanks. I had not thought about it. The best would be to centralize all the authentification process checks in the same file : isEnabled? isDeleted? Update last login.

Answer (score 1):

Friend you can use this to inject the entityManager by a constructor

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $userManager){
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
}
```

And in the checkPreAuth you call it

```
public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user){
    if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
        return;
    }
    if ( $user->getDeleted() || !$user->getEnabled()  ){
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }else{
        // BELOW IS WHAT I TRY, BUT FAIL.
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
        $this->userManager->persist($user);
        $this->userManager->flush();
    }
}
```